# Python aggregate sum Quantity

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this

```
sale_id brand   Qty
1       Toyota  1
1       Toyota  2
2       Honda   1
2       Toyota  1
3       Lexus   3
```

Is there a function to convert it to:

```
sale_id Toyota Honda Lexus
1       3      0     0
2       1      1     0
3       0      0     1
```

So basically I´m creating columns equal to the sum of all quantities bought per car type by sale_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or `pd.crosstab` with aggregation function of `sum`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['sale_id'], df['brand'], df['Qty'], aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
brand    Honda  Lexus  Toyota
sale_id                      
1          0.0    0.0     3.0
2          1.0    0.0     1.0
3          0.0    3.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
s = df.groupby(['sale_id','brand']).Qty.sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[223]: 
brand    Honda  Lexus  Toyota
sale_id                      
1            0      0       3
2            1      0       1
3            0      3       0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(index='sale_id',
                        columns='brand',
                        values='Qty', 
                        fill_value=0,
                        aggfunc='sum')
print(new_df)

brand    Honda  Lexus  Toyota
sale_id                      
1            0      0       3
2            1      0       1
3            0      3       0
```

Comment: also, you forgot the agg function = 'sum'